# symlink not is recursive

Tags: apache-httpd, symlink

`ln -s /home/marcelo/MEGASync/localhost /var/www/html/`

I am using symlink from terminal ubuntu to get all sites from my /home/marcelo/MEGASync/localhost/ to my www of my apache. I Access localhost from my browser and I get this:

```
flavio/        #I access these -----
one-site/
other-siter/
more-one-site/
```

I have this in my content of the path: localhost/flavio

```
nub/             #and now, I access these
flavio/
flavio2/
```

When I accessed this path in browser, I get this error:

```
Not Found  
The requested URL /nub was not found on this server.
```

But I have a structure of codeigniter in this path: /localhost/flavio/nub/

What's ocurred in this?
And how to I will solve this?

Comment: Apache by default won't follow unsafe (i.e. pointing outside of its `DocumentRoot`) symlinks.  I think there's a config option that can be set to allow it, though.

Comment: @TobySpeight If that's what the OP is asking, a better way to deal with it would be to just point `DocumentRoot` to `/home/marcelo/MEGASync/localhost`...

Comment: @SatoKatsura Good idea, I will go test this!

Comment: @SatoKatsura it seems to me that it gave me the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I would ask you to check the status of selinux,  if it's in enforcing mode then you should allow apache context for this path /home/marcelo/MEGASync/localhost

To check the selinux status :

## sestatus